# Apparently my API Proxy does not exist

Tags: apigee

I've created a new API Proxy and deployed revision 1 into production, but when I call my API I just get:

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Internal server error APIProxy revision 1 of MyProxy does not exist in environment prod of organization MyOrg",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "messaging.adaptors.http.ServerError"
        }
    }
}
```

Not the most helpful error message in history. Any pointers where to start debugging this would be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the wrong url for your API, so it could not be found.  If you haven't added any API key checking or additional authorization, you should be able to copy the url directly from the API details page in the prod Deployments line.  Start a trace session and paste that url into the URL box.  Test what happens when you do that trace.

If you have any additional security or other features that would alter the API, you would need to make those changes to the URL before sending it.  If you're still having a problem, send an email to help@apigee.com.

Comment: Thanks. I have the full URL, including key and all, but it does not work. The reason I am confused by the error message is not for a lack of trying to debug, it is that it claims that my Proxy does not exists. Will mail you directly to figure this out.