# Internal server error APIProxy revision 22 of oauth does not exist in environment test

Tags: apigee

Hi i tried to send a request to my endpoint which was working perfectly before the emergency maintenance by Apigee people (reply email attached)

now i am getting this error message which actually does not make any sense to me:

```
{"fault":
   {"faultstring":"Internal server error APIProxy revision 22 of oauth does not exist in      environment test of organization accenture-845","detail":
{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.ServerError"}}}
```

Please have a look into my screenshot also may be it will help to understand more.

[image]

this is the email i recieved from apigee people before this error started coming:

[image: emergency maintenance]

Note: i have tried this solution already : [Apparently my API Proxy does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017506/apparently-my-api-proxy-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried undeploying and redeploying the latest revision to your test environment? You can do this by clicking on the test dropdown pointed to by your right arrow. Doing this should undeploy the proxy. Then hopefully clicking it again will successfully redeploy the proxy.

Another thing to try would be to use the "Save as New Revision" item on the Project dropdown to save revision 20, 21, and 22. Then try to undeploy from test and deploy revision 22 and see if that fixes it.

You could also try using the [management API calls for proxies](http://apigee.com/docs/api/apis-0) to deploy and undeploy proxies.

Comment: I tried doing all the it seems that apigee was down that time. Its working fine now tho. thanks @mike